# Java code semphore

Tags: java, semaphore

I have the following java code. this give diiferent output in each. I thing i have to use semaphores and mutex but i don't know where to use. And i am new to multithread so can someone tell me where are the threads in this program. And what can i do to get consistent result

**Account.java**

```
package banking;

public class Account {
    final String accountHolder;
    final String accountType;
    double balance=0;

    public Account(String name, String type,double credit) {
        this.accountHolder = name;
        this.accountType = type;        
        this.balance=credit;
    }

    public void deposit(double credit) {
        balance += credit;
    }

    public void withdraw(double credit) {
        balance -= credit;
    }

    public void addinterest(double rate) {
        balance *= (100+rate)/100.0;
    }

}
```

**Banking.java**

```
package banking;

public class Banking {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Application started");

        Account savings  = new Account("Pete","Super Saver",1000);
        Account checking = new Account("Pete","Free Checking",1000);

        System.out.println("\nBeginning of month");
        System.out.println(savings.accountType + ":\t"+ savings.balance);
        System.out.println(checking.accountType + ":\t"+ checking.balance);
        System.out.println("Total before \t"+ (checking.balance+savings.balance));


        Interest checkInterest = new Interest(checking, -10);        
        Interest saveInterest = new Interest(savings, 10);   
        Transfer transfer = new Transfer(savings,checking,100);  


        checkInterest.start();
        saveInterest.start(); 
        transfer.start();


        Thread.sleep(520);
        System.out.println("\nEnd of month");
        System.out.println(savings.accountType + ":\t"+ savings.balance);
        System.out.println(checking.accountType + ":\t"+ checking.balance);
        System.out.println("Total  after \t"+ (checking.balance+savings.balance));
        System.out.println("Main thread finished");
    }
}
```

**Interest.java**

```
package banking;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


class Interest extends java.lang.Thread {
    final Account myAccount;
    double myRate;

    public Interest(Account account, double rate) {
          this.myAccount=account;
          this.myRate = rate;
          setName("Interest");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

         System.out.println("Interest this month on "+  myAccount.accountType + ":\t" + myAccount.balance*myRate/100.0);
         myAccount.addinterest(myRate);

          //System.out.println(getName() + " to account " + myAccount.accountType + " successfully applied");
    }



}
```

**Transfer.java**

```
package banking;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class Transfer extends java.lang.Thread {    
    final Account myAccount1;
    Account myAccount2;
    double myAmount;

    public Transfer(Account account1,Account account2, double amount) {
          this.myAccount1=account1;
          this.myAccount2=account2;
          this.myAmount = amount;
          setName("Transfer");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        myAccount1.withdraw(myAmount);
        myAccount2.deposit(myAmount);

        System.out.println(getName() + " from " + myAccount1.accountType + " to " + myAccount2.accountType + " successfully applied");
    }



}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is each `Interest`-object has its own `mutex`, therefore they are not synchronized in any way wrt. each other. You have to move the synchronization-objects to a central points, so each change on `balance` in an `Account` object is mutially-exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

No need for semaphores. Just add `synchronized` before every method in `Account` class. For example:

```
public synchronized void deposit(double credit) {
    balance += credit;
}
```

[EDIT]

When a method is `synchronized`, the runtime environment guarantees that if multiple threads call the same method in a given object, only one of them executes and the others wait until it finishes. Then one other thread executes and so on.

[EDIT2]

Also, don't access the data members of the `Account` directly. Make them `private` and define `synchronized` getters and setters. The real problem in your program is in the transfer operation:

```
    myAccount1.withdraw(myAmount);
    myAccount2.deposit(myAmount);
```

It is not atomic in this way. Imagine for example that the Interest thread executes before these two lines in an execution, and between them in another. You will get different final results. To solve this, add the following method to the `Account` class:

```
public synchronized void transfer (Account to, double amount) {
     this.withdraw (amount);
     to.deposit(amount);
}
```

and replace the two lines by this call:

```
  synchronized(myAccount2) {
       myAccount1.transfer(myAccount2, myAmount);
  }
```

The reason for adding the `synchronized` block around the call of the `transfer` method is that you need to acquire both locks of both objects in order to perform a transfer. The `synchronized(myAccount2)` acquires the lock of myAccount2 and the call of `transfer` acquires the lock of myAccount1, as the method `transfer` is synchronized.

[EDIT3]

There is also a conceptual problem in your program. You are calculating interests of two account and transferring money between them, all that in parallel threads. So, it is normal to have different results if you transfer the money first then calculate the interests, or if you calculate the interests first then transfer the money. Try to do the math by hand. If you want to sequence the operations, don't use threads, just call methods sequentially

Comment: While this seems to be a solid solution, it may be helpful for OP, if you describe what `synchronized` does and why his/her attempt is not working.

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: i have added synchronized before every method in Account class. But it is still displaying different answers each time i run

Comment: @user_sr I also modified the answer to solve other problems. I think that this should work fine. Don't forget to remove the semaphore and the mutex.

Comment: A.Wabbi i have tried your solution but still displaying different output

Comment: @user_sr I edited the answer a third time! Sorry for this. Please try it.

Comment: @user_sr Read the last paragraph of my answer. You will always get different outputs depending on the order of transfer/interest calculation operations. You don't have control on this order when you use threads. The synchronization is important, but it does not give order to the operations execution. Once again, in real life, when you calculate interests AFTER the transfer, you get different result compared to calculating the interests BEFORE the transfer.

Comment: I want to solve this problem so i can get only one answers to this question. How can i do that

Comment: @user_sr You CAN'T do that using threads. Instead, replace threads by normal classes and call their methods sequentially in the main. Why do you think that you must get one answer to the question? Do you understand my previous remark?

Comment: You can sleep main thread between child threads starts to keep the order. But whole transfer must be in one transaction. Call operations sequentially in one thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread.join() for checkInterest and saveInterest. So that transfer starts when both finishes

```
checkInterest.start();
saveInterest.start(); 

checkInterest.join();
saveInterest.join();

transfer.start();
```

Comment: how can i do that please help. i don't know much about thread.How can use thread.join